# В чем возникает проблема при остановке запущенного файла?

Tags: python

Запускаю в PyCharm файл, который ищет COM порт и принимает из него информацию. Все работает отлично, но при остановке вылетает в консоли: Process finished with exit code -1. Почему не ноль? Что я делаю не так?

Код:

```
import glob
import sys
from time import sleep

import serial


def serial_ports():
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    res = result[0]
    print(result[0])
    return res


ser = serial.Serial(str(serial_ports()), baudrate=9600, timeout=2)  # настройка порта


class COMPORTREAD():
    while 1:
        lines = ser.readline()
        print(lines.decode('UTF-8').strip())
        lines1 = str(lines.decode('UTF-8'))
        # print('lines1 = ' + lines1)
        # print( lines1.split('=', 1)[0])
        if lines1.split('=', 1)[0] == 'gerkon_down':
            print('match!!! gerkon_down = ' + str(lines1.split('=', 1)[1]))
        if lines1.split('=', 1)[0] == 'gerkon_up':
            print('match!!! gerkon_up = ' + str(lines1.split('=', 1)[1]))
        if lines1.split('=', 1)[0] == 'gerkon_alarm':
            print('match!!! gerkon_alarm = ' + str(lines1.split('=', 1)[1]))
        if not lines:
            sleep(10.0)
```

Comment: А как ты завершаеш программу? Если Ctrl+c то такой способ генерирует ошибку.

Comment: @Sergei Malanin Я запускаю и завершаю программу в PyCharm стандартным способом (кнопку или зеленый треугольник или квадратную красную нажимаю) или Shist+F10 и Ctrl+F2.

Comment: Ну вот эта красная кнопка посылает сигнал к завершению. Который интерпретируется как рантайм эррор. Это нормальное поведение. У тебя скрипт не может завершиться сам, на сколько я понимаю.

Comment: Мой совет: иногда полезно плзапускать свою программу из терминала. Пайчарм удобная штука но иногда надо и ручками. В пайчарме кстати есть интегрированный терминал. Если бы ты запустил в терминале то если в программе не предусмотрено завершение скрипта то тебе пришлось бы послать Ctrl+c что бы завершить скрипт.

Comment: @Sergei Malanin большое спасибо за подсказку. Данный скрипт планирую запускать как демона, так что он должен завершаться с основным скриптом. Из Ваших объяснений я понимаю, что код выхода -1 в данном случае ни на что не влияет в моем случае и в принципе все Ок? По поводу ручек - принял к сведению, спасибо.

Comment: В твоём случае думаю это нормальное поведение. Если твой скрипт постоянно читает данные и должен работать всегда. В таком случае для него любое завершение это ошибка. Так же тебе надо подумать как перезапускать твой скрипт если он упал.

Comment: Пометь пожалуйста ответ как решение.

Comment: @Sergei Malanin Спасибо за развернутые объяснения. Теперь и в самом деле думаю, как перезапускать скрипт при  обрыве связи например. Except не хотят ловиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот эта красная кнопка посылает сигнал к завершению. Который интерпретируется как рантайм эррор. Это нормальное поведение. У тебя скрипт не может завершиться сам, на сколько я понимаю.